# Поставил Laravel на хостинг, /login выдает 404

Tags: laravel, хостинг, ispmanager

Доброй ночи, столкнулся с проблемой, использовал Laravel 5.7 + Laravel Nova.
На локалке все окей, заливаю на хостинг получаю ошибку 404.

http://crm.rus-hockey.ru/register

При этом основная страница работает нормально, то есть роутер рабочий, не работает именно страница логина или регистрации и нова. Роуты все прописаны, база подключена и проверена.

Представить не могу в чем проблема.

Comment: Банально, но Auth::routes() в web.php есть?

Comment: модуль php `mod_rewrite` включён?